# How to copy mac-address string in the structure member of type uin8_t

Tags: c, printf, structure

**Unexpected MAC-address value obtained using snprintf function**

Why do I get "Unexpected mac-address value. I have big string (unsigned char data[DATA_LEN ]) to parse and copy mac address to the structure member. I am getting completely different string. Please help on this, Thank you.

Input data string:

```
unsigned char data[512] = "its-STRING: 18 22 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AC 12 00 20 00 00 00 C8 8C DF 9D 57 12 20 00 00 00 29 \n";
```

Output of the program

```
Parsed Mac from string =  8C DF 9D 57 12 20
copied MacAddress == 32:30:3a:33:38:00
```

From the above mentioned string i have to extract the mac-address "8C DF 9D 57 12 20"and then i have to copy this mac-address into the following structure

```
typedef struct my_stuct_s{
   uint8_t mac_addr[18];
  }my_stuct_t;
```

Below is how I have the coded.

```
#define PARSE_OFFSET 89
#define END_OFFESET 19
#define DATA_LEN 512
#define ADDR_LEN 6


typedef struct my_stuct_s{
   uint8_t mac_addr[ADDR_LEN];
   uint8_t item;
}my_stuct_t;


int main()
{
  unsigned char data[DATA_LEN] = "its-STRING: 18 22 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AC 12 00 20 00 00 00 C8 8C DF 9D 57 12 20 00 00 00 29 \n";
  unsigned char strv6[ADDR_LEN];

  unsigned char *data1 = NULL;

  my_stuct_t shm_memory;

  memset(strv6, 0,sizeof(strv6));
  memset(&shm_memory, 0,sizeof(my_stuct_t));

  if ((strcmp(data, "") ) != 0)
  {
    data1 = &data[0];
    data1 = data1 + PARSE_OFFSET;
    snprintf(strv6, END_OFFESET,"%s\n", data1);

    printf("Parsed Mac from string = %s\n", strv6);
    snprintf((char *)&shm_memory.mac_addr, ADDR_LEN,
            "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",
            strv6[0], strv6[1],
            strv6[2], strv6[3],
            strv6[4], strv6[5]);
 printf("copied MacAddress == %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n ",
          shm_memory.mac_addr[0],
          shm_memory.mac_addr[1],
          shm_memory.mac_addr[2],
          shm_memory.mac_addr[3],
          shm_memory.mac_addr[4],
          shm_memory.mac_addr[5]);
  }
  else
    printf("\n empty string");


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your parse offset starts at 89 and number of chars to be copied are 18.

   ```
   #define PARSE_OFFSET 89
   #define END_OFFESET 19
   ```

   should be

   ```
   #define PARSE_OFFSET 90
   #define END_OFFESET 18
   ```
2. Length of the char array which stores the address should be 19.

   ```
   unsigned char strv6[19];
   ```
3. You need to use `sscanf` not `sprintf` as below.

   ```
   sscanf(strv6, "%02x %02x %02X %02x %02x %02x\n",
     &shm_memory.mac_addr[0],
     &shm_memory.mac_addr[1],
     &shm_memory.mac_addr[2],
     &shm_memory.mac_addr[3],
     &shm_memory.mac_addr[4],
     &shm_memory.mac_addr[5]);
   ```